# connecting to database using angular and php

Tags: angularjs

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

app.controller("usercontroller",function($scope,$http){
$scope.insertData = function(){
  $http.post(
    "insert.php",    
    {'yourName':$scope.yourName, 'lstName':$scope.lstName,
 'passwrd':$scope.passwrd}).success(function(data){
      alert(data);
    });
}
});
```

I have this code and console returns an error that says "success is not function"how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

use `then` instead `success` .

```
.then(onSuccess)
function onSuccess(data){
}
```

And i think in you should do like that

html

```
<input ng-model="formData.yourName">
<input ng-model="formData.lstName">
<input ng-model="formData.password">
```

in js

```
       function yourcontroller($scope){
        var $scope.formData={};
            $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'insert.php',
            data:$.param($scope.formData)
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

            })  .then(onSuccess,onError)
        function onSuccess(data){
      //handle success
        }
        function onError(reason){
      //handle error
}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.success` is depreciated, Use `.then`. Like :

```
 .then(function(data){
    alert(data);// handle data
  }, function(error) {
        //handle error
  });
```